# If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $A+kI_n$ and $B+kI_n$ are similar for all scalars $k$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Two $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$ are *similar*, written $A \sim B$, if $B = P^{-1}AP$ for some invertible matrix $P$. How do we prove that $A \sim B$ implies that $A+kI_n \sim B+kI_n$ for all scalars $k$? In other words, how do we obtain $B+kI_n = P^{-1}(A+kI_n)P$ given that $B = P^{-1}AP$? Can we just add $kI_n$ to both sides of the equation? How do you prove that two modifications of similar matrices are also similar?

Answer (score 2):

Just multiply the matrices: $P^{-1}(A+kI_n)P = P^{-1}AP + kP^{-1}P = B + kI_n$.

Comment: How do matrices distribute over the parentheses? I'm slightly confused by your operations.

Comment: Just like usual variables: $X(Y+Z) = XY+XZ$ and $(X+Y)Z=XZ=YZ$. So $P^{-1}(A+kI_n)P = (P^{-1}A+kP^{-1})P = P^{-1}AP+kP^{-1}P$.